# How to get accessToken to my Azure App Service from inside MSTest c# code

Tags: c#, azure, access-token, bearer-token, azure-managed-identity

I have web app for API calls (without UI, only the service) and I am writing MSTest project to test the API.
This is my AuthConfiguration inside the web app code:

```
 public static void ConfigureWebApiAuth(IAppBuilder app){
        // User Authentication
        app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
            new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                TokenValidationParameters = UserAuthTokenValidationParameters,
                MetadataAddress =   AadApplicationMetadataAddress,
                TokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler()
            });
}
        public static TokenValidationParameters UserAuthTokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidAudience = AadApplicationClientId,
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            AuthenticationType = UserContext,
        };
```

How can I create a suitable token from my MSTest?

I tried:

```
    AzureServiceTokenProvider localToken = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
    var token = await getTokenProvider().GetAccessTokenAsync("https://xxx.azurewebsites.net");
```

also:

```
AccessToken token =
    await new DefaultAzureCredential()
    .GetTokenAsync(
        new TokenRequestContext(
            new[] { "https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/.default" }
        ));
```

It works only with https://storage.azure.com/, https://vault.azure.net/, and so on and not with my app service url.
I am getting the errors:

> Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://xxxxx.azurewebsites.net, Authority: . Tried the following 3 methods to get an access token, but none of
> them worked. Tried to get token using Managed Service Identity. Access
> token could not be acquired. A socket operation was attempted to an
> unreachable network.Exception Message: Tried to get token using Visual
> Studio. Access token could not be acquired. Exception for Visual
> Studio token provider Microsoft.Asal.TokenService.exe : TS003: Error,
> TS004: Unable to get access token.  'Failed to refresh access token'
> Exception Message: Tried to get token using Azure CLI. Access token
> could not be acquired. 'az' is not recognized as an internal or
> external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: You create a token for testing by logging into the API in the same way that your application does.  There isn't (or shouldn't be) a 'magic' token that just works.   You should create a 'test' account with username/password/credentials and use that to login with, to generate a token.

Comment: Can't I use User assigned managed identity? I created one and added it inside the 'identity' tab of my web app.

Comment: If you are using v2.0 endpoint, the scope should be `{your_client_id}/.default`. Could you try with it?

Answer (score 0):

The `scope/resource` in your code is incorrect. And there is an [article](https://joonasw.net/view/calling-your-apis-with-aad-msi-using-app-permissions) for you to understand.

```
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
string apiToken = await azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("your API's client id/app id or App ID URI");
```

The scope should be added `/.default` when using v2.0 endpoint.